# Redirect 301 from /store to /

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My store was once named domain.com/store but now it's just domain.com

But all my google links are now dead due to this, how can I fix this? Can I make a rewrite some how so that all old domain.com/store/category/item.html will be redirected to domain.com/category/item.html ?

Comment: `domain.com/store/category/item.html` to `domain.com/category/item.html`, is that all or there are more items. If that's right, which strings in the URLs are fixed and which dynamic?

Comment: It's all links. I used this, seems to work!

    `Redirect 301 /store/ http://www.domain.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect 301 /store/ http://www.domain.com/

Adding this to my .htaccess solved my problem